# Array list update to database

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist, struts

I am trying to update my database using values in array list . Following is the code i am trying.

```
String query = "insert into login values(? , ?)";
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            for(int i = 0;i < rowlength; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(rowList.get(i));
            statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setInt(1, rowList.get(i));
            statement.setString(2, rowsList.get(i+2));
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            }
        } 

        catch (SQLException e) {
            try {
                throw new ServletException("DB interaction failed", e);
            } catch (ServletException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
                }
```

Its fetching following error in console for all values of loop.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass    (WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass   (WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at com.aipl.struts.action.ExcelDbAction.getConnection(ExcelDbAction.java:60)
at com.aipl.struts.action.ExcelDbAction.execute(ExcelDbAction.java:126)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Can anybody direct me in what i am doing wrong or their is another way of updating table in database.

Thank you////

Comment: You must put the Postgresql JDBC driver on your classpath.

Comment: @NewBee You have to add the Postgres DB Driver in classpath

Comment: seems the driver library is not included...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error appears when jvm could not find jdbc-driver on its `classpath`. make sure you have configured your classpath correctly

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is that the PostgreSQL database driver is not on the classpath of your application. Based on the stacktrace, I'm guessing you are using Tomcat; so take a look at [The PostgreSQL JDBC Interface](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/tomcat.html) documentation to find out where you should place it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the Database Driver. For example for SQL Server 
             `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
               Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`

Also instead of closing your resources in a finally block you can use the try-with resources (Oracle Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature of Java.